# Filtros en vista blade con Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, filtro, laravel-livewire

Me encuentro realizando un proyecto inmobiliario y realizo una búsqueda y mando todas las propiedades del controlador a la vista.

```
public function busquedaPropiedades(Request $request){


    //BUSCAMOS CATEGORIA Y LA ENVIAMOS A ALGOLIA
    //Buscamos la categoría seleccionada
    $categoria = $request->get('categoria');
    //Enviamos el id de la categoría seleccionada
    $categoria_id = Category::where('nombre_categoria', $categoria)->pluck('id');

    //UTILIZAMOS ALGOLIA PARA BUSCAR LA CATEGORÍA Y LO QUE EL USUARIO ESCRIBA
    $propiedadesObtenidas = Property::search($request->get('ubicacion'))->where('category_id', '=', $categoria_id[0])->get();
    
     return view('web.secciones.busquedasPropiedades', [
        'propiedadesObtenidas' => $propiedadesObtenidas,
        'categoria' => $categoria
    ]);
}
```

En la vista muestro lo que el usuario buscó.

Ahora estoy investigando como puedo agregar "filtros de búsqueda" algo como la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro información de como realizar este procedimiento. Y me gustaría que me brinden una orientación de como se hace este filtrado en la vista.

Por ejemplo si envío la categoría desde el controlador al filtro de la vista:

```
$resultadosCategorias = Category::get();
```

¿Como es que la vista se debe actualizar con lo seleccionado por el usuario?

```
@foreach($resultadosCategorias as $categorias)
                      
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="rbCategoria" id="rb-categoria" value="option1" checked>

    <label class="form-check-label" for="rb-categoria">
        {{ $categorias->nombre_categoria }}
    </label>
    <br>
@endforeach
```

¿Como puedo realizar que la vista muestre lo que selecciona el usuario?

Suponiendo que el foreach muestra los siguientes items

1. venta
2. alquiler

En radiobutton y el usuario selecciona uno que forma es la correcta para renderizar la vista?

**EDICIÓN:**

Al enviar los valores seleccionados por el usuario siempre tengo un problema con la vista que no encuentra una u otra variable o no muestra nada, basandome en el ejemplo @L.Flor

Para que me actualice la vista hago lo siguiente:

```
@if($categories == 'null')

  @foreach($categories as $categoria)
           ...
  @endforeach

@endif
```

Y esto me genera una vista sin resultados. Como puedo validad si me llegan datos y mostrar los valores correspondientes?

Comment: @BetaM gracias como siempre por tu ayuda! edite la pregunta, creo que ahora está bien no? abrazo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ves en la documentación, en la parte de [rendering-components](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/rendering-components), podrás notar que vista y componente pueden interactuar de la siguiente manera:

En tu componente debes tener los criterios de búsqueda y también las categorías que serán retornadas mediante el método `render()`.

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Nav;

use Livewire\Component;

class SearchCategories extends Component
{
     // Criterios de búsqueda
     public $tipoPropiedad;
     public $tipoOperacion;
     
     // Categorias
     public $categories;

     public function render()
     {
          $this->categories = Category::
                where('tipo_op', $this->tipoOperacion)
                ->where('tipo_prop', $this->tipoPropiedad)
                ->get();

          return view('livewire.vista');
     }
}
```

Posteriormente, en tu vista, deberás tener reflejado esto. Sólo a modo de ejemplo te pongo esto:

```
<div>
   <input type="text" wire:model="tipoOperacion" />
   <input type="text" wire:model="tipoPropiedad" />

   @foreach($categories as $categoria)
           ...
   @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Hola @L.Flor si bien tu explicación me genero un panorama más claro lo que no logro realizar la actualización de las vistas. Edito la pregunta así te muestro lo que hago.

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione agregando una vista recursiva. Muchas gracias @L.Flor tu ayuda me sirvió muchísimo!!

Mi vista recursiva

```
@each('web.secciones.partials.filtroCategoria', $categorias, 'categoriaFiltrada')
```